# Non-Abelian Fourier Analysis

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

I'm currently thinking to generalize a known result on abelian groups to non-abelian groups. This is the problem. Fix an abelian group $G$. We know that:

$\mathbb{E}_{\chi\in \hat{G}}\chi(g)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}1 & g=0 \\ 0 & g\neq 0\end{array} \right.$

It's not possible to easily generalize this identity in the non-abelian case, because if we replace characters with representations, they are matrices of different dimension so the product doesn't make sense. My question is whether there exist a plausible generalization of this identity in the case where $G$ is a non-abelian group.

We also have a Fourier inversion formula in the Abelian case. Do we have a suitable inverse formula in the non-abelian case?

I would also appreciate if one could introduce me some reference about non-abelian Fourier Analysis.

Comment: One place you could start is Folland's _A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis_

Comment: As for your specific question: if $G$ is a finite group then your identity can be interpreted as a special case of: "columns of the character table are orthogonal" -- see e.g. the book of James and Liebeck for an introduction to some basic character theory on finite groups

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is also an inverse formula in the non-abelian case?

Comment: I think the correct notion of "inverse formula" is that the character table, once suitably normalized is a unitary matrix, hence its inverse is its conjugate transpose. So this suggests if you want the inverse formula your Fourier transform must be between the space of conjugacy classes and the space of irreps.

Comment: The book by Ruzhansky and Turunen studies the Fourier series on all compact Lie groups: http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~ruzh/Book-Ruzhansky-Turunen-about.htm. The abelian case (tori) is quite classical. The book is available online. See section 7.6 for Fourier analysis. There are inversion formulas and Parseval identities and all that. (This is not helpful for finite groups, but might be a generalization in the direction you need.)

Comment: @WillSawin Actually, for any compact group there is a perfectly good notion of non-abelian fourier transform and its inverse, you just have to go to matrix valued functions on the dual object. See Section 5.3 of Folland's book.

Comment: You may want to read the paper "L'algebre de Fourier d'un groupe localement compact" by P. Eymard. It doesn't give you inversion formula, but it is the C*-algebraic framework generalizing Fourier analysis to non-abelian groups.

Comment: You **might** want to read Eymard's paper, but I'm afraid it will tell you **nothing** about non-abelian Fourier inversion, nor about how character theory can be extended to certain non-abelian groups. Indeed, anything at the level of generality of Eymard's paper applies to groups which are not Type I, and as far as I know, for such groups there is as yet no meaningful way to set up Plancherel, Fourier inversion and so on.